# Can you use /dev/kvm without adding it as a device?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, linux-device-driver, kvm, mknod

If I add `--device=/dev/kvm` to the docker run command, I can access KVM. But is it also possible to do it without that parameter?

The reason I ask is because I recently found out I can access `/dev/net/tun` without specifying it as a `--device` just by using the `mknod` command to create that file from inside the container.

I hope its also possible to create `/dev/kvm` using `mknod` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `mknod kvm c 10 232` ?
you can find the major and minor number of any device by running `ls -al /dev`

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. Seems like you cannot automaticly create it in the container like with /dev/net/tun.

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: QEMU fails to start, complaining about no permissions for the KVM device. I already tried chmod 777 on /dev/kvm, but it made no difference. Maybe the reason that it works for /dev/net/tun is that the container is running with the NET_ADMIN capability. So from that POV it would be weird if I was able to access KVM without any privileges.